# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

sql is throwing this error what could this mean?

```
select *
from deal.d
inner join product_request pr on pr.deal_id =d.deal_id
inner join party p on p.party_id =dp.party_id
where p.user_id='QABSMA11' and pr.Lien_Position_Num (2,3);

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 - "invalid relational operator"
*Cause: 
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 171
```

Answer (score 2):

`and pr.Lien_Position_Num (2,3)`

should be

`and pr.Lien_Position_Num IN (2,3)`

(And also what dasblinkenlight wrote: use `deal d` instead of `deal.d`)